# Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (cannot load such file -- mysql2) (LoadError)

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, ruby, redmine

I am trying to install Redmine on Ubuntu and currently having an error if open Redmine page:

> Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install
>   activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (cannot load such file -- mysql2)
>   (LoadError)

If I execute the following command, I success (was separate challenge):

```
# gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter
Successfully installed activerecord-mysql2-adapter-0.0.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for activerecord-mysql2-adapter-0.0.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for activerecord-mysql2-adapter-0.0.3...
```

How to fix?

**UPDATE**

Some information:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]


$ gem -v
1.8.23

$ dpkg -s redmine
Package: redmine
Status: install ok installed
Priority: extra
Section: web
Installed-Size: 13445
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Version: 2.4.2-1
Depends: ruby | ruby-interpreter, ruby-railties-3.2 (>= 3.2.13-2~), ruby-rails-observers,                                                      dbconfig-common, redmine-sqlite | redmine-mysql | redmine-pgsql, ruby-rack (>= 1.4.5~) | r                                                     uby-rack1.4, ruby-coderay (>= 1.0.6), ruby-net-ldap (>= 0.3.1), ruby-openid, ruby-rack-ope                                                     nid, libjs-scriptaculous, debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0
Pre-Depends: debconf
Recommends: ruby-passenger, libfcgi-ruby1.9.1 | libfcgi-ruby
Suggests: ruby-rmagick, bzr, cvs, darcs, git, mercurial, subversion
Breaks: redmine-plugin-botsfilter (<= 1.02-2), redmine-plugin-recaptcha (<= 0.1.0+git20121                                                     018)
Conflicts: ruby-passenger (<< 3)
```

Looks like there are some conflicts!

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.2.0, 3.2.19)
actionpack (4.2.0, 3.2.19)
actionview (4.2.0)
activejob (4.2.0)
activemodel (4.2.0, 3.2.19)
activerecord (4.2.0, 3.2.19)
activerecord-mysql2-adapter (0.0.3)
activeresource (4.0.0, 3.2.19)
activesupport (4.2.0, 3.2.19)
arel (6.0.0, 3.0.3)
builder (3.2.2, 3.0.4)
bundler (1.7.9)
coderay (1.1.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
globalid (0.3.0)
hike (2.1.3, 1.2.3)
i18n (0.7.0)
journey (1.0.4)
json (1.8.1)
loofah (2.0.1)
mail (2.6.3, 2.5.4)
mime-types (2.4.3, 1.25.1)
mini_portile (0.6.1)
minitest (5.5.0)
multi_json (1.10.1)
mysql2 (0.3.17)
nokogiri (1.6.5)
polyglot (0.3.5)
rack (1.6.0, 1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.4.1, 1.3.4)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (1.0.5)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.1)
rails-observers (0.1.2)
rake (10.4.2)
sprockets (2.12.3, 2.2.3)
thread_safe (0.3.4)
tilt (2.0.1, 1.4.1)
treetop (1.5.3, 1.4.15)
tzinfo (1.2.2, 0.3.42)
```

(ran under my username, not `root` and not `www-data`)

Comment: Are you sure that you installed the Gem system-wide (i.e. `sudo gem install…`), or did you install it for a local Ruby version only? The Redmine process might be using the system Ruby/Gem.

Comment: I am not sure! Moreover, I suspect that something this kind happened! But how to know?

Comment: This command was issued under `root` user. Also tried `sudo`.

Comment: Well, how do you run Redmine? Which server? What user is this server run as? This user should have the gem installed.

Comment: Server is `apache2` and it runs under `www-data`. Redmine was installed with `apt-get`. Os is Ubuntu `14.04`. What does it mean `gem` should be installed for `www-data`?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and give a little more info? Like your `gem list` and version of Ruby and Gem (`ruby -v`, `gem -v`), and version of Redmine? Did you already do a `bundle install` in the folder where you have Redmine? Did you reboot the server?